All breakers tripped at once
All of the breakers in my main curciut breaker box tripped at once. I have two other boxes that were unaffected. Power was restored after placing them all back in the on position, but I am concerned about what could have caused them all to trip.

There are a few possibilities. Any storms happening at the time? Can you upload a picture of the panel showing all the breakers?

Yes, can you post photos of the box in question please?

were they in the tripped position or the off position?  If they were tripped, you would need to take them to off before on.

Are they GFCI or just current overload devices? A power-line surge might have caused the issue with GFCI's. Whatever caused the tripping, they did their job, protecting the house. If all can be reset, then likely the wiring is OK, but check for burned-out devices around the house.

Do these breakers have "Test" buttons?

They went off completely, I’m used to one tripping when we make coffee while running the dishwasher.  No test buttons.
I can’t figure out how to add the photo.
